# javascript function not call in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I have two functions that make two combobox with jqwidgets libraries. two functions are mostly like each other. I call them in `$(document).ready(function ()`, but first function is work well and the second not even call. I put the codes those in one function, but the second part never run.

```
function f1() {
     var url2 = "/autosuggest/JsonOrigins.aspx";

     var source2 = {
         datatype: "json",
         datafields: [{
             name: 'id'
         }, {
             name: 'name'
         }],
         url: url2,
         async: false
     };
     var dataAdapter2 = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source2);
     // Create a jqxComboBox
     $("#originsjqxWidget").jqxComboBox({
         source: dataAdapter2,
         multiSelect: true,
         displayMember: "name",
         valueMember: "id",
         width: 145
     });


     $("#arrow").jqxButton({});
     $("#arrow").click(function () {
         $("#originsjqxWidget").jqxComboBox({
             showArrow: false
         });
     });

     $("#originsjqxWidget").on('change', function (event) {
         var items = $("#originsjqxWidget").jqxComboBox('getSelectedItems');
         var selectedItems = "Selected Items: ";
         $.each(items, function (index) {
             selectedItems += this.label;
             if (items.length - 1 != index) {
                 selectedItems += ", ";
             }
         });
         $("#log").text(selectedItems);
     });
 };

 function f2() {
     var url = "/autosuggest/JsonTag.aspx";

     var source = {
         datatype: "json",
         datafields: [{
             name: 'id'
         }, {
             name: 'name'
         }],
         url: url,
         async: false
     };
     var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

     $("#categoriesjqxWidget").jqxComboBox({
         source: dataAdapter,
         multiSelect: true,
         displayMember: "name",
         valueMember: "id",
         width: 145
     });


     $("#arrow").jqxButton({});
     $("#arrow").click(function () {
         $("#jqxComboBox").jqxComboBox({
             showArrow: false
         });
     });

     $("#categoriesjqxWidget").on('change', function (event) {
         var items = $("#categoriesjqxWidget").jqxComboBox('getSelectedItems');
         var selectedItems = "Selected Items: ";
         $.each(items, function (index) {
             selectedItems += this.label;
             if (items.length - 1 != index) {
                 selectedItems += ", ";
             }
         });
         $("#log").text(selectedItems);
     });
 }


 $(document).ready(function () {

     f1();
     f2();

 });
```

Comment: Does anything appear in your _Console_?

Comment: $("#log").text(selectedItems);
                               });
                               }; what is ';' at end there?

Comment: This can happen if you have an error in your javascript: your script stops running. Are you sure you don't have any error (check the console) ?

Comment: How do you know the second one isn't called?

Comment: try to call f2() and comment the f1(). check whether f2() is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ; after your first function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var source2 = {
     datatype: "json";
     datafields: [{
         name: 'id'
     }, {
         name: 'name'
     }],
     url: url2,
     async: false
 };
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you have an extra ; at the end of function f1

```
        function f1(){ 
...
                 if (items.length - 1 != index) {
                     selectedItems += ", ";
                 }
             });
             $("#log").text(selectedItems);
         });
     };
```

Comment: it worn't work the same if there's a syntax error :)